# Using rawinput() to assign to variables until a certain keyword is given in Python

Tags: python, raw-input

Not sure if this is a simple question or not, pretty new to Python. Let's say I want to gather data about a user, but don't know how much info they have. How would I make it so they can keep on entering data, and when they enter a keyword like "END" the program would stop gathering data?

Comment: So... `while data != "END":`?

Comment: First of all im sure that if you have a search you'll find many answer ! but briefly you can use a `While` loop, for handle such tasks : `while input !='END' : #do stuff`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iter` and a for loop:

```
for line in iter(lambda: raw_input("Enter details or "END" to quit"),"END"):
    print(line)
```

Or use a while loop:

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter names or end to quit")
    if inp == "END":
        break
    #  do whatever with inp
```

Comment: the iter method is definately my favorite way to do this :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, me too :) especially as you can use it in a list comp too

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code, if you have no idea where to begin:

```
user_input = [] # list of data user is entering
while True:
    data = raw_input("Enter data: ")
    if data.lower() == 'end':
        break
    else:
        user_input.append(data)

print user_input
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is you could store all the information in a list (or swap for however you want to store the info) using something like this:

```
data = []

while True:
    user_input = raw_input("Enter something:")
    if user_input == "quit":
           break
    data.append(user_input)
    print (data)
```

Fancier would be building a `dict` with key-value pairs for data-types and subsequent information. Doing so would follow a similar logic (or at least one approach would follow a similar logic).